# Method 'getExtensionAttributes' must be overridden Error in Magento 2.1.2 - NGINX Server

Tags: nginx, bug, magento-2.1.2

I have installed a fresh clean package of Magento 2.1.2 but i am getting the following error:

> Method 'getExtensionAttributes' must be overridden in the interfaces which extend 'Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface'. Concrete return type must be specified. Please fix :\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface

I have changed the opcache.save_comments to 1 in my opcache.ini file, and still didn’t work, anyone have a clue how to fix this?

By the way, I have installed a earlier version of Magento 2 and everything works fine with no error, it this a Magento 2.1.2 Bug?

Comment: are you using any module?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled opcache module of PHP, please ensure that the `opcache.save_comments` directive is set to `1`.

```
opcache.save_comments=1
```

Do not forget to restart your web server and/or PHP process container after making changes to the ini (opcache.ini or php.ini - depending on your OS and PHP installation) file.